# alliteration in coda : an Old English example?

Tags: old-english, poetry

(1) Can the coda, [the final part of a syllable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllable), be part of an [alliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration)? Do we have any example in the literature?

(2) in [Beowulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf).25 ("in mǣ́ġþa ġehwǣ́re | mán ġeþéo͡n.", [stressed syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(linguistics)) with an acute accent), why would the correction of replacing ġehwǣ́re by ġehwǣ́m would produce a "double alliteration" ?

---

I'm stuck with what I know about alliteration: [source: [wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration)

```
In literature, alliteration is the conspicuous repetition of identical initial consonant sounds [...]
```

This definition, along as others I read elsewhere, seems to imply that only the initial (onset) sound of a syllable is part of an alliteration; see examples like "humble house," or "potential power play."

In Old English, [alliterative verses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliterative_verse) demand that two half-lines be linked by the alliteration of *certain* stress syllables.
Two examples:

```
simple alliteration in [ʃ] (Scýldes/Scédelàndum) as in

    0019 Scýldes éafera | Scédelàndum ín. 


double alliteration in [w] (wḗox,wólcnum,wéorðmỳndum) as in

    0008 wḗox under wólcnum, | wéorðmỳndum þā́h,
```

In Beowulf.25, the manuscript reads:

```
simple alliteration in [m] : mǣ́ġþa/mán

    0025 in mǣ́ġþa ġehwǣ́re | mán ġeþéo͡n.
```

For some reasons[note a, see infra], it'd better to have a double alliteration here; some experts suggest[note b, see infra] to correct the verse and write:

```
    0025 in mǣ́ġþa ġehwǣ́m | mán ġeþéo͡n.
```

**So, if ġehwǣ́m with its final -m produces a double alliteration, it seems that the onset AND the coda take part of an alliteration, in contradiction with the initial definition of an alliteration.**

Hence my two questions:

(1) Can the coda, the final part of a syllable, be part of an alliteration? Do you have any example in the literature?

(2) In Beowulf.25 Why would the correction of replacing ġehwǣ́re by ġehwǣ́m would produce a "double alliteration" ?

---

**[note a]** Be.25 being a 'A' type avec anacrusis. Suggestion read in Klaeber's Beowulf, in the note about the verse #25.

**[note b] relevant excerpts in *Klaeber's Beowulf*:**

Klaeber's Beowulf, p. 114 (note about verse 25) :

> "25. in mǣgþa ġehwǣre. Verses of type A with anacrusis usually have
>   double alliteration (Appx.C §35). The exception here is very likely
>   due to the scribal substitution of analogical LWS fem. ġehwǣre for
>   earlier genderless ġehwǣm (the latter preserved w. fem. ref. in 1365;
>   [...]) [...]"

Klaeber's Beowulf, p. 333 (Appendix C §35)

> "(§35.) Type A. [...] There are no uncontested examples without double
>   alliteration [...] Thus *in mǣgþa ġehwǣre* 25a is not impossible, but
>   the substitution of ġehwǣm would mark an improvement [...]"

Comment: Do you mean the onset *of* the final syllable?

Comment: @vectory : No, I'm talking very generally about the final consonant of a syllable. In my example (Beowulf.25) it is true that it is the final consonant of the last syllable, but this is just a coincidence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked [Professeur Fulk](https://english.indiana.edu/about/emeriti/fulk-robert-d.html), Professor Emeritus of English, one of the authors of *Klaeber's Beowulf*, who was kind enough to answer me quickly and to allow me to reproduce his email.

> [...] if it is assumed that ġehwǣre is a late substitution for
>   original ġehwǣm, the alliteration is improved because the metrical
>   pattern x / x x / x usually appears only when the verse contains two
>   alliterating staves. In the metrical pattern x / x x /, on the other
>   hand, it may be that just one of the staves alliterates. And so
>   substituting original ġehwǣm for ġehwǣre does not alter the
>   alliteration, but it does convert the metrical pattern to one in which
>   double alliteration is not required. [...]

Thank you very much, Professor.

Answer (score -2):

It's not so much that *-m* causes aliteration in the strict sense, but if innovated *-re* falls on the stressed beat, it breaks the trochee (or iamb) of the staff rhyme and thus the alliteration. That's unlikely, if the final *-e* is chiefly elided to contract the words. The aliteration is in principle with the *m-* of the response, *man g...*, yes.

The repeated *g-* onset makes it a double aliteration (a *Schüttelreim*), in my mind, though your given example seems to imply something else, but note its additional rhyme *under*, *-yndum*.

PS: whoopsy, I meant a mere (a b, a b), but [Schüttelreim](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sch%C3%BCttelreim) fits the bill rather nicely.

Comment: "if innovated -re falls on the stressed beat" : it doesnt, isn't it ? We have *in mǣ́ġþa ġehwǣ́re*, not *ġehwǣré* or *ġehwǣ́ré*.

Comment: "The repeated g- onset makes it a double aliteration" : as far as I know, the alliteration is based upon stressed syllables but initial *ġe-* is never stressed in Old English.

Comment: I think that counts for the prefix *ge-* but I'm not sure it generalizes for all stems *g-*.